# preventing brute force attack on samba server

Tags: security, samba

I have a LAN with many users(clients) in it. Each of them has a private samba share folder.

How can I prevent somebody (within the same network) brute forces another account (so he can access somebody else data)?

Googling brings only: "Samba shares should not be on the public internet". But I am in my local network.

I think many admins have exact this "problem" (for example companies or university admins)

So is there any way to allow only 3 login attempts per minute or blacklisting the ip of an client after 3 attempt?  Or any other solution for this problem? 
I tried fail2ban, but there is no host ip address in the log file.

More Info:

- Clients mostly windows 7 or above
- Samba current Version on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I dont know, what is too bready on the question "preventing brute force attack on samba server". I found a simple solution: 
`sudo pdbedit -P "bad lockout attempt" -C 5`
`sudo pdbedit -P "lockout duration" -C 15`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I should admit that you cannot make it **100% safe**.

For securing Samba in your LAN, I think the only option you have is to set some rules in iptables to block anyone attempting wrong password for X times. - hitcount number is your choice, I suggest 2 or 3

Here you can see some simple rules set in iptables, I haven't used IP Address in the commands below, but I recommend you set IP Address following by its CIDR number so it'll become more safe

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 137 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name netbios-ns

$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 137 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 20 --hitcount 2 --rttl --name netbios-ns -j DROP

$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 138 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name netbios-dgm

$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 138 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 20 --hitcount 2 --rttl --name netbios-dgm -j DROP

$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 139 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name netbios-ssn

$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 139 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 20 --hitcount 2 --rttl --name netbios-ssn -j DROP

$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 445 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name microsoft-ds

$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 445 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 20 --hitcount 2 --rttl --name microsoft-ds -j DROP
```